# How to enable Firefox device simulation with WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, browser-automation

I would like to run some Selenium tests in Firefox, using [the device simulation feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode#Device_selection) to test for mobile devices.

For Chrome, this is exposed through [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation), but `FirefoxOptions` doesn't seem to have any such option, and my search for any related profile preference or command-line option didn't turn up anything.

Is there a way to do this in Firefox? I'd prefer it to Chrome because the built-in device list of Chrome seems to be very outdated.